# Enqueue Wordpress plugin scripts below all other JS

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I am developing a simple Wordpress app but I am having an issue as all of the plugin scripts are rendered before those which are enqueued in my `functions.php`.

Here is a sample section of the `functions.php`:

```php
function my_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('app-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/app.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script('app-js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

The important this to note is that (following best practice my JS is set to render at the bottom of the page.

I also have couple of plugins running on the theme. The problem is that the output looks like this:

```html
<!-- Note the plugin appears first -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/acl-plugin.js'></script>
<!-- And the main JS appears second -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme/javascripts/app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I force Wordpress to display the main JS (which I believe is rendered by `wp_head()` ) to appear above the plugin scripts? That way the plugins can reference JS functions that are in the main theme.

Comment: Try and add the priority parameter to the hook for app.js and see if it works. like **`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts', 1 );`**. By default it is 10, so lets call it early and see if this works for you

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, your `app.js` *is* at the bottom of the page (output by wp_footer, not wp_head), what's the issue?

Comment: Woops, type-o in there. Thanks @Milo what I meant was how to I ensure that the PLUGINS appears below the main script. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: @MarutiMohanty thanks for the suggestion. Adding the priority has moved it! Do you want to add this as an answer (so you get the rep) or I can outline the answer for others instead.

Comment: @Sheixt sure, done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and use/add the priority parameter of the hook for `app.js` and see if it works.

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts', 1 );`

By default it is 10, so lets call it early and see if this works for you